# Efficient cache-aware fetching of multiple entities given their ids

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

This is JPA2 running on Hibernate.

I want to retrieve multiple instances of the same entity type, given their ids. Many of them will already be in the persistence context and/or second-level cache.

I tried several approaches, but all seem to have their drawbacks:

- When I iterate over the ids with `entityManager.find(id)`, I get one query for each non-cached item, that is, too many queries.
- With a query of the form `SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.id in (:ids)`, the cached entries will be reloaded from the db.
- I can manually check the cache beforehand for each of the ids using `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().contains(id)`. This works for the second-level cache, but will return false on entries that are in the persistence context, but not in the second-level cache.

What is the best way of doing this without choosing between loading inefficiently and loading too much?

Answer (score 0):

You should* be able to speculatively pull an entity out of the session cache like this:

```
T obj = entityManager.getReference(entityClass, id);
boolean inSessionCache = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().isLoaded(obj);
```

This still leaves you with a pretty gross solution, i admit.

(* might)